# Evaluate definite integral using limit of a sum definition

Tags: definite-integrals, summation

> From the definition of a definite integral as the limit of a sum, evaluate 
>   $$\int_a^b\frac{1}{\sqrt x}dx$$

---

My progress so far:

$\begin{align}
\int_a^b\frac{1}{\sqrt x}dx & =\lim_{n\to\infty}h\times\bigg(f(a)+f(a+h)+\cdots+f\big(a+(n-1)h\big)\bigg) \\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}h\times\bigg(\frac1{\sqrt a}+\frac1{\sqrt {a+h}} +\cdots+\frac1{\sqrt {a+(n-1)h}}\bigg)
\end{align}$

---

After this point, I cant't think of a way to combine the reciprocals of square roots into a neat form. Usually a convenient summation formula is applicable but how would I proceed in this case?

Comment: Are you *sure* you're not given some sort of constants $a,b$? I don't recall ever seeing one without them in my school work, seems like it might make things a little too difficult at first glance.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Yes, all the other questions in the exercise also have limits $a$,$b$. Using $nh=b-a$ still works even if you don't know what $a$ and $b$ are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume $0\leq a\leq b$. In order to cope with the square root function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ it is convenient to use *variable* length intervals with length $j^2\frac{b-a}{n^2}$. When taking square roots we can factor out $j$  and summation is expected to become simpler. The corresponding Riemann sum is
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{\color{blue}{a}+ j^2\frac{b-a}{n^2}}}\cdot\left(j^2\frac{b-a}{n^2}-(j-1)^2\frac{b-a}{n^2}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align*}
But it's still not easy due to the constant $\color{blue}{a}$. To overcome this difficulty we write the integral as difference of two improper integrals
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=\int_{0}^{b}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx-\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx\tag{2}
\end{align*}
If the limit of the Riemann sums of the improper integrals exists we have found the wanted Riemann integral and we are done.

> We subdivide the interval $[0,b]$ in 
>   \begin{align*}
> [0,b]=\bigcup_{j=1}^n\left[(j-1)^2\frac{b}{n^2},j^2\frac{b}{n^2}\right]
> \end{align*}
>   with  length
>   \begin{align*}
> j^2\frac{b}{n^2}-(j-1)^2\frac{b}{n^2}=\frac{(2j-1)b}{n^2}\qquad\qquad1\leq  j\leq n
> \end{align*}
>   and  obtain the Riemann sum
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\int_{0}^b\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{j^2b}{n^2}}}\cdot\frac{(2j-1)b}{n^2}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sqrt{b}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(2-\frac{1}{j}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=\sqrt{b}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(2n-H_n\right)\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2\sqrt{b}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>
> We finally  conclude  from (2) and (6)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\int_{a}^b\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=2\left(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}\right)}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we have the  now convenient representation (1) evaluated at  $a=0$.
- In (4) we   do   some  simplifications and     factor  out    terms not dependent on $n$ resp.   $j$.
- In (5) we note the *[Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)* $H_n=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j}$ grow asymptotically with  $\log n$, so that
  \begin{align*}
  \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{H_n}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}=0.
  \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful solution. However, while using $log \ n$ to approximate $H_n=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j}$, there is difference of exactly $\gamma = 0.57721\ldots$ between the two when $\lim_{n\to \infty}$. So maybe adding the constant value would make this already brilliant answer even better?

Comment: Also, $j^2\frac{b}{n^2}-(j-1)^2\frac{b}{n^2}=\frac{(2j-1)b}{n^2}$ is I believe what you intended to write.

Comment: @s0ulr3aper07: You're welcome and many thanks for pointing to the mistakes.

Comment: @s0ulr3aper07:  With respect to the harmonic numbers I think it's sufficient to use the dominant term $\log n$ of the asymptotic expansion, since we are dividing by $n$ when taking the limit.

Comment: I tried a similar approach for $\int_a^b{\frac1{x^2}dx}$ with variable length intervals of length $\sqrt{j} \frac{b-a}{\sqrt{n}}$ but unlike the resulting calculations above, these new calculations are not as clean. Specially because I get $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j}(\sqrt{j}-\sqrt{j-1}$). Could you provide some help there please?

Comment: @s0ulr3aper07: At the time I'm busy. I can have a look at it in the evening hours. In the meantime you could post this question to give others the possibility to provide helpful answers. Regards,

Comment: Hey, if you could have a look that'd be awesome! Here's the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168351/evaluate-int-ab-frac1-x2dx-using-limit-of-a-sum-definition